# Parking stop ideas

Tags: car, efficiency

Need help parking my truck at an angle in my three car garage, without hitting my wife’s sedan.  I have an HD 2500 with a headache rack that only fits in the garage at an angle with my wife’s car in the third bay.  My truck is too wide for that bay.  It needs to be in the garage during winter.  It fits but I need something to warn me of her car and the wall on my driver's side where the garage is more shallow.  Tennis balls won’t work because I can’t see my wife’s sedan when I start to pull in the garage.  I need to know where I’m at and when I’m in.  Ideas?  The truck does fit but I have to get out and constantly check my space while parking. I cannot drill stops on the floor because I do not own this house.  Thanks.  I’m using her account.

Comment: A diagram would really help.

Comment: I have a feeling that you should try the opposite of what you're currently doing. If you're trying to back in, then try driving straight in instead. Or if you're angling your truck towards her car, try angling it to the opposite corner if the garage so there is a wall there instead of a car.

Comment: Fit Park Assist sensors, as recommended by runningt below...

Comment: Driving forward.  Third bay is deeper by 12' easily but my truck is to big to fit through the single door.  The side Im using is the standard two door garage side pulling in further into third bay in front of her car.

Answer (score 2):

Buy or find a heavy dumb-bell (weightlifting equipment) and place it on the floor as a tire stop (so your tire rollsinto the handel). You could also use 45lb weight plates to make drive-between guards... so two spaced to let your tire pass between if you are in the right place. You’ll feel the plates in the steering if you are to one side.

Answer (score 1):

Does your hd 2500 have park assist sensors at all?
If not, did you consider buying and installing one of [these](http://mycarneedsthis.com/the-best-parking-sensor-systems-to-buy/) park assist sensors?
The link is to an article showing and comparing several models.

Comment: Can you please explain what 'these' are? Not everybody can open links all the time and if the link goes down there is no way to find out what you meant.

Comment: Does not have park assist.   Her car does...

Comment: @Janifer: As I said, you can buy external park assist sensors. and attach it to your car.

Answer (score 1):

Craig Constantine suggested drive-between guards made of free weights. Another drive-between idea is long 2x4 boards, with other wooden blocks nailed on top of them every couple of feet. The boards would provide a "channel" for your truck, and the larger blocks (maybe a 4x4 post sawed into 6" sections?) would provide bumps that you could feel as you are driving in.

[image]

Comment: This may work with some modifications...need to research..

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve a problem you shouldn't have in the first place.

You're trying to straighten out *after* you're already half way in the garage, like this, and ending up hitting your wife's car, and maybe the garage door sides too, like this:

[image]

**Instead**, just straighten out *before* entering the garage, so you'll drive straight in with no chance of hitting anything on either side.

- Either turn further back like this:

  [image: turn further out]
- Or make a partial turn towards the garage (1-2), then back up & straighten out (2-3), before driving straight in (3-4):

  [image]

---

Or, if for some reason it's impossible to straighten out first, you can still use tennis balls, but taped from the ceiling hanging in a curtain just along side / in front of your wife's car. Then you can see & bump into the tennis ball curtain just before you would hit the actual car.

Just a couple tennis balls (or anything that won't scratch & is heavy enough not to blow around) would work, or you could go crazy with tennis balls like in this image:

[image]

Comment: No no no.. the HD 2500 4x 4 pick up is too long for the regular two car garage. It has to go in at an angle to utilize the space in front of my wife’s car in the third bay.  But thanks anyways everyone we ended up using a cone with a tennis ball on top and a reflective pole that sticks up out of that past the top of my truck so I can see where I’m at in relation to her car on that side.  Problem solved!

Comment: That's unfortunate, didn't "see" the problem without a pic. Sometimes pickups are too tall for a garage, but length... [looks like](https://preview.tinyurl.com/y83v6xg7) a 2017 GM 2500HD could be 230" (19' 2") to 258.4" (21' 6.4")... standard garage length is about 20'. If there's anything at all in front of the space (table, etc) clearing it out would be great. Might as well pick an answer as correct (check-mark), mine does mention tennis balls so it's close (*hint* ;-) and hanging tennis balls from the ceiling means they're always in the same place, the cone could get bumped & moved...

Answer (score 0):

I created a figure of your situation and I guess it is correct. Anyway, my solution is given below:
[image]

Having a parking sensor is the ultimate solution, even then finding out hack in my logic is, using balloons.If you don't have to invest some money in the sensor, I would suggest you go for this:

1. Before parking your car, find some balloons(large sized are most welcome).
2. Fill them with air and fix them using cello tape to the wall of your garage and surface of your wife's car.
   (filling them to their maximum is most appreciated)
3. Take care while selecting sellotape, it should not harm your wife's car's color, otherwise, you will have to worry a lot.
4. Also, try to stick these balloons where you don't have a visual while parking.
5. Now, if the plot is ready, get inside the car. Open every one of its windows so that bursting sound of the balloon could be heard if any of the sides cross the limit.
6. Get the car inside on reverse gear. If you hear balloons sound, take action accordingly.

Another solution is to use markings of paint on ground.Perform this when you are free as this will take some more time.

1. Put your wife's car in her slot, but at the extreme critical position which could take a hit when you reverse your car.(This situation is considered deliberatly sothat if by chance you wife's car lie in that position, your markings should not do wrong to you)
2. Now drive your car in reverse mode, with utmost care.
3. As and when you change the direction of car to safety, put it on handbrake, get outside of the car, get some paint to mark a point on floor so that next time when you drive in, you can correlate with this point on floor.(Try to take point based upon the outer edge of body of your car)
4. Perform step 3 until you feel confident that you can put your car to garage.

Comment: Balloons do not keep air for long. They will have almost no air in less than a week. Maybe you could replace them with a plastic storage bag that includes a "zipper".

Comment: Thanks @BrettFromLA I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

The point is to take half of your car at 45 degree angle and once half is in, turn you tires to max and move ahead.However, while reading some [random article](https://carhq.org/alignment-cost/) which gave a tip that you may correct your wheel alignment to ensure better accuracy

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please add the essential parts from that page in your answer. If that link expires, this answer may become invalid. Also, try to explain first sentence of your answer.